# Cardview Columns using Devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

created a few seconds ago
Hi,

I am creating a web page in asp.net based on data from a database. This should result in a number of tab pages with card views on each tab with 5 columns and a maximum of 20 rows. The tab pages are working, the rows are working but the columns will not change from the default 3 columns.

I have tried setting the columnCount property at different stages, post and pre databinding. This getting frustrating.

I am having problems with setting a card views column count programmatically. I am setting it, have tried to set it in different places but it always goes to the default 3 columns :(

I am using C# in Visual studio 2017.

Here is the code I am using:

```
SqlDataSource sds = new SqlDataSource();
public string fName;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string fid = Request.QueryString["FID"];
sds.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBaseConnection"].ToString();
sds.SelectCommand = "select name from [flashboard] where flashboardid = " + fid;
DataView fDet = (DataView)sds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

fName = fDet.Table.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
TitleLink.InnerHtml = fName;

sds.SelectCommand = "SELECT flashboardtabid, name FROM [FlashboardTab] WHERE flashboardid = " + fid+" order by SeqNo";
DataView fTab = (DataView)sds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
TabPage tabDet;
ASPxPageControl tpc = ASPxPageControl1;
ASPxCardView cardGrp;
CardViewTextColumn cName;
CardViewHyperLinkColumn cEvidence;
foreach (DataRow tab in fTab.Table.Rows)
{
tabDet = new TabPage();
tabDet.Text = tab["name"].ToString();
tabDet.Name = "Tab"+tab["flashboardtabid"].ToString();
tabDet.ActiveTabStyle.Width = Unit.Percentage( 80);

cardGrp = new ASPxCardView();
cardGrp.ID = "CardGroup" + tab["flashboardtabid"].ToString() ;
tabDet.Controls.Add(cardGrp);

tpc.TabPages.Add(tabDet);

cardGrp.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

ASPxCardViewPagerSettings cvps = new ASPxCardViewPagerSettings(cardGrp);
cardGrp.EnableTheming = true;
cardGrp.Theme = "SoftOrange";
cvps.Visible = false;
cvps.SettingsTableLayout.ColumnCount = 5;
cvps.SettingsTableLayout.RowsPerPage = 20;

cardGrp.DataSource = GetData("SELECT cardid, Description, EvidencePage, SmartViewid FROM [flashboardcard] WHERE flashboardtabid = "+tab["flashboardtabid"] + " order by SeqNo");
cardGrp.Attributes.Add("Width", "80%");
cardGrp.Attributes.Add("style", "margin:auto");
cName = new CardViewTextColumn();
cName.Name = "Description";
cName.FieldName = "Description";
cEvidence = new CardViewHyperLinkColumn();
cEvidence.Name = "EvidencePage";
cEvidence.FieldName = "EvidencePage";
cEvidence.PropertiesHyperLinkEdit.Text = "Evidence";
cardGrp.Columns.Add(cName);
cardGrp.Columns.Add(cEvidence);

var layoutitem1 = new CardViewColumnLayoutItem(); // cardGrp.CardLayoutProperties.FindColumnItem("EvidencePage");
layoutitem1.ColumnName = "EvidencePage";
layoutitem1.ShowCaption = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
layoutitem1.HorizontalAlign = FormLayoutHorizontalAlign.Center;
var layoutitem2 = new CardViewColumnLayoutItem();
layoutitem2.ColumnName = "Description";
layoutitem2.ShowCaption = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
layoutitem2.HorizontalAlign = FormLayoutHorizontalAlign.Center;
layoutitem2.ParentContainerStyle.Font.Bold = true;
layoutitem2.ParentContainerStyle.Font.Size = FontUnit.Medium;
cardGrp.CardLayoutProperties.Items.Add(layoutitem2);
cardGrp.CardLayoutProperties.Items.Add(layoutitem1);
cardGrp.DataBind();
}
}

DataView GetData(String queryString)
{
DataView ds = new DataView();
sds.SelectCommand = queryString;
ds = (DataView)sds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
return ds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue with ColumnCount, I recommend you define it directly in the control's SettingsPager.SettingsTableLayout.ColumnCount property instead of specifying it in a new ASPxCardViewPagerSettings instance:

```
cardGrp.SettingsPager.SettingsTableLayout.ColumnCount = 5;
cardGrp.SettingsPager.SettingsTableLayout.RowsPerPage = 20;
```